# Why is the evaluation of f different using rules and using arguments to it as a function?

Tags: functions, replacement, rule

I will provide all the code I used at the end of the question.

I was trying to evaluate a function `f` with the following signature (which I'll give the details at the end):

```
f[x_List, t1L_List, t2L_List, c_List]
```

when I try to evaluate it arguments given to it directly it gives me one number:

```
f[xdata, t1data, t2data, cdata]
```

returns (after processing it numerically with `N`):

```
72.499
```

which I believe is the correct one because I've implemented `f` in matlab and they agree.

However, when I try to evaluate it with rules, it seems to give a different result:

```
f[x, t1, t2, c] /. Join[Thread[Flatten[x] -> Flatten[xdata]], Thread[Flatten[t1] -> Flatten[t1data]],Thread[Flatten[t2] -> Flatten[t2data]], Thread[Flatten[c] -> Flatten[cdata]]]
```

returns (after processing it numerically with `N`):

```
72.6803
```

It might look at little strange that I am doing:

```
Join[Thread[Flatten[x] -> Flatten[xdata]], Thread[Flatten[t1] -> Flatten[t1data]],Thread[Flatten[t2] -> Flatten[t2data]], Thread[Flatten[c] -> Flatten[cdata]]]
```

to do the rule substitution, but the issue is that `x, t1, t2, c` are all lists (of potentially nested lists) of symbols. Thus, its crucial that all the variables in those lists get assigned to the correct value.

I have tried to visually debug it by looking what values each variable in x is assigned too, but they all look fine. So I was wondering, if there was a good way to check what the difference between these two evaluations is? Is there a way to use equality checks to check this? I wish I even knew what the real issue was, maybe the rule substitution was done incorrectly?

Are there any suggestions people have to check why the computation of these two is different?

One may ask why I'd do such a strange thing to evaluate `f`, but the truth is that I am not interested in evaluating f, but evaluating its derivative, so the real intention is to first compute the derivative and then immediately after use rule substitution to evaluate it at a certain point. As in:

```
g[f_, theta_] := D[f[x,t1,t2,c], theta] /. Join[Thread[Flatten[x] -> Flatten[xdata]], Thread[Flatten[t1] -> Flatten[t1data]],Thread[Flatten[t2] -> Flatten[t2data]], Thread[Flatten[c] -> Flatten[cdata]]]
```

this actually runs for a value of theta that is a symbol inside the lists (as in `t2L1x1y` as an example at the end of the code), however, even if it runs with no errors, if the substitution:

```
Join[Thread[Flatten[x] -> Flatten[xdata]], Thread[Flatten[t1] -> Flatten[t1data]],Thread[Flatten[t2] -> Flatten[t2data]], Thread[Flatten[c] -> Flatten[cdata]]]
```

doesn't work for the simple case of evaluating f, then I can't trust it using the derivative either.

---

**Appendix**

I will paste the full code here so that people can reproduce the exact results that I am getting.

For the definition of f:

```
f[x_List, t1L_List, t2L_List, c_List] := Sum[ c[[k2]]  a3k2[x, t1L, t2L[[k2]]], {k2, 1, Length[c]}]

a3k2[x_List, t1L_List, t2k2_List] := Exp[-mynorm[ a2[x, t1L] - t2k2]^2]

a2[x_List, t1L_List] := Join[Flatten[Table[a2np[x[[np]], t1L[[np]]], {np, 1, Length[x]}]]]

a2np[xnp_List, t1Lnp_List] := Table[Exp[-mynorm[xnp - t1Lnp[[dd]]]^2], {dd, 1, Length[t1Lnp]}]

mynorm[x_List] := (Sum[(x[[i]])^2, {i, 1, Length[x]}])^(1/2)
```

For the definition of the actual data I used:

```
x = {{x1p1x, x1p2x, x1p3x}, {x2p1x, x2p2x, x2p3x}}

t2 = {{t2L1x1y, t2L1x2y, t2L1x3y, t2L1x4y}, {t2L2x1y, t2L2x2y, t2L2x3y, t2L2x4y}, {t2L3x1y, t2L3x2y, t2L3x3y, t2L3x4y}, {t2L4x1y, t2L4x2y, t2L4x3y, t2L4x4y}}

t1 = {t1L1p, t1L2p}

t1L1p = {t1L1p1v, t1L1p2v}

t1L2p = {t1L2p1v, t1L2p2v}

t1L1p1v = {t1L1p1v1x, t1L1p1v2x, t1L1p1v3x}

t1L1p2v = {t1L1p2v1x, t1L1p2v2x, t1L1p2v3x}

t1L2p1v = {t1L2p1v1x, t1L2p1v2x, t1L2p1v3x}

t1L2p2v = {t1L2p2v1x, t1L2p2v3x, t1L2p2v3x}

c = {c1, c2, c3, c4}
```

and for the actual numbers I used:

```
xdata = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}/Norm[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, 2]

t1data = {{Range[1, 3]/Norm[Range[1, 3], 2],Range[4, 6]/Norm[Range[4, 6], 2]}, {Range[7, 9]/ Norm[Range[7, 9], 2], Range[10, 12]/Norm[Range[10, 12], 2]}}

t2data = {Range[13, 16]/Norm[Range[13, 16], 2], Range[17, 20]/Norm[Range[17, 20], 2], Range[21, 24]/Norm[Range[21, 24], 2], Range[25, 28]/Norm[Range[25, 28], 2]}

cdata = {29, 30, 31, 32}
```

Comment: Look at your definition for `t1L2p2v`. There are two `t1L2p2v3x`'s. With code like this, you *always* need fresh eyes if something is not working. (By the way, this question was good: it supplied all the information. But: it's always a good idea to see if you can reproduce your problem for a simpler version of what you're doing, a *minimal example* in the common parlance here. You probably would have discovered that the code worked for the minimal example, which would have suggested to you that there was a typo in the real problem.)

Comment: Why don't you put semicolons at the ends? Don't all those unnecessary lines of output get in the way?

Comment: @MichaelE2 I guess for the symbolic variables, you are right, the output is in the way, but for the ones were actual numerical values are used, I sort of looked at the values to make sure they were correct and matched with some of the other assignments. In particular I also print out: `Join[Thread[Flatten[x] -> Flatten[xdata]], 
 Thread[Flatten[t1] -> Flatten[t1data]], 
 Thread[Flatten[t2] -> Flatten[t2data]], 
 Thread[Flatten[c] -> Flatten[cdata]]]` sorry should have mentioned this I guess. Thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: In the first case, I get [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/3KULx.png), not the approximate number.  You must have used `N`, I guess?

Comment: @MichaelE2 yes I did use `N`. Sorry for not saying that, its sort of hard to write a perfect question! Though I've updated it so that it makes sense.

Comment: Typo in `t1L2p2v`.  Ah, well.  It happens, esp. with such names. :)

Comment: @MichaelE2 I agree, I do whatever I want in my notebook. But it doesn't hurt to be more considerate with the people helping me and putting the semi colons so that their notebooks are not a mess. I will put them in a bit. If people want to see the output they can opt out from the semicolons themselves. :)

Comment: @MichaelE2 yea...that naming was a bad idea...but its hard to choose good names because each coordinate has sort of a meaning (at least to me), hence the naming...maybe I should just number things from 1 to n next time...the issue too is that the underscore is a special thing in mathematica and also that mathematica cannot take derivatives wrt to indices in a list. Because really, behind all this craziness, I am just trying to take the symbolic derivative with respect to the nth component or whatever the entry of the tensor might be.